# Using combinatorics to find all possible ways of opening and reading letters

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a way to solve a combinatorics problem. Lets say I have $10$ unique letters and I have to find all possible ways in which I can open and read them. In order to read a letter I have to open it first. So all I have is that I have to open and read $10$ letters, that's $20$ things to do and I have to get all possible outcomes, with one restriction - open a letter before reading it.

> How can I calculate the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of solving is as follows

Let us denote the 10 openings as $O_i$, and the readings as $R_i$ for $i={1,2,...,10}$. There are $20!$ possible orderings, but we require that $O_i$ comes before $R_i$. This will happen in half of the cases, each independently of the others. So, our solution is
$$\frac{20!}{2^{10}} = 2375880867360000$$

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

It is
$$
\binom{20}{2} \binom{18}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2} = 2375880867360000.
$$
Out of the 20 positions, you can choose 2 for opening and reading letter 1, but the order is determined, so there are $\binom{20}{2}$ ways of picking these. Then you do that for letter 2 and 18 remaining positions, etc.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help, I just dont get how this assures that the opening of a letter comes before the reading.

Comment: You' re very welcome

Comment: Say you have picked position 3 and 17, say. Then the opening *must* be in position 3, and the reading in position 17. So all that matters is the 2-element subset. And there are ${k \choose 2}$ ways to pick those.

Comment: Awesome, cheers!